# I cant compile my .py to an .exe(missing .dll files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm, pyinstaller

I really dont know what more to do so i can compile my project in an .exe.
Tried many tutorials, including one i found here and on github without success.

**i use pycharm community version 2021.1**

my cmd:

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.19042.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install pyinstaller
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.5.24)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (56.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

my powershell:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python -m pip install pyinstaller                                                               Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.5.24)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (56.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

my pycharm terminal:

```
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>\pyinstaller -w -F bobeiruda.py
'\pyinstaller' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
english: (pyinstaler is not recognized as an internal or external command, an operable program or a file in lots)

(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>python --version
Python 3.9.5

(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>pip --version
pip 21.1.2 from c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>pyinstaller --version
4.3

(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>
```

pycharm pt2

```
(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>pyinstaller bobeiruda.py --onefile
100 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
100 INFO: Python: 3.9.5
116 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
118 INFO: wrote C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso\bobeiruda.spec
147 INFO: UPX is not available.
167 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\anton\\PycharmProjects\\Curso',
 'C:\\Users\\anton\\PycharmProjects\\Curso']
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
3302 INFO: checking Analysis
3503 INFO: checking PYZ
3641 INFO: checking PKG
3641 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
3641 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
4297 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python
.exe
4298 WARNING:   Reason: 'The file is empty'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 737, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 684, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso\bobeiruda.spec", line 21, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 438, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(self.toc, cdict=kwargs.get('cdict', None),
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 200, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 279, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())
  File "c:\users\anton\pycharmprojects\curso\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 956, in get_python_library_path
    raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Python library not found: libpython39.dll, libpython3.9m.dll, libpython39m.dll, libpython3.9.dll, python39.dll
    This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
    This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.

    * On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
      * apt-get install python3-dev
      * apt-get install python-dev
    * If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)


(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>
```

i followed the [Missing dll files using PyInstaller on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073059/missing-dll-files-using-pyinstaller-on-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) tutorial and nothing changed, still cant compile my file:
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bpTB.png)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [auto py to exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/):
It is self explaing as soon as you install it through Command... you access it trough the command and you tip "auto py to exe" then you can choose your .py and convert it into a exe

Comment: ```
(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>auto py to exe bobeiruda.py
'auto' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes. ->english: (auto is not recognized as an internal or external command, an operable program or a file in lots)

(venv) C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\Curso>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pyinstaller filename.py -w` or `pyinstaller filename.py`.
Remove `--onefile` most of the times it creates issues.
And see whether you are opening the app from dist folder. If you open with build folder it will show error.

Comment: i tried and both returned the same error message as in "pycharm pt2"